# DataSet or Reader or What?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When using a Class to get one row of Data from the Database what is best to use:

- A DataSet?
- A Reader and do what store the data in a Structure?
- What else?

Thanks for your time, Nathan

Comment: However I could use a DataReader and store the one row results in a structure to pass back from a WebService would that be a good idea?

I am not using the DataSet like most would.  I am only reading when getting the DataSet. 

To overcome the fact a reader has to be closed I could store in a structure.

Comment: I think I get it now... I could use a Class Object to return the Data from a DataReader when I am only wanting one row and Return a DataSet when I am wanting more then one row.  Does this sound best?

Comment: You're on the right track, but since you've already got classes, you could just as easily return a `Collection<YourClass>`.  Avoiding DataTables and DataSets is generally a good idea (they're great for tabular data, but are often abused and can hinder good OOP)

Comment: Thanks STW so Class in the case would be like BEANs in Java right where it is holding data for only one item?   Or since it is a Collection can it be holding Multiple Classes (or Beans)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DataReader is always your best choice--provided that it is compatible with your usage.  DataReaders are very fast, efficient, and lightweight--but they carry the requirement that you maintain an active/open db connection for their lifecycle, this means they can't be marshalled across AppDomains (or across webservices, etc).

DataSets are actually populated by DataReaders--they are eager-loaded (all data is populated before any is accessed) and are therefore less performant, but they have the added benefit of being serializable (they're essentially just a DTO) and that means they're easy to carry across AppDomains or webservices.

The difference is sometimes summed up by saying "DataReaders are ideal for ADO.NET ONLINE (implying that it's fine to keep the db connection open) whereas DataSets are ideal for ADO.NET OFFLINE (where the consumer can't necessarily connect directly to the database).

Answer (score 0):

DataAdapter (which fills a DataSet) uses a DataReader to do so.

So, DataReader is always more lightweight and easier to use than a DataAdapter. DataSets and DataTables always have a huge  overhead in terms of memory usage. Makes no difference if you are fetching a single row, but makes a huge difference for bigger result sets.

If you are fetching a fixed number of items, in MS SQL Server, output variables from a stored proc (or parameterized command) usually perform best.

Answer (score 0):

if you use a reader you must have a open connection to your database generally a DataReader is used for fetch a combo or dataGrid, but if you want to stock your data in memory and you close our data base connexion you must use Datatable

Note : excuse my english level

Answer (score 0):

If you just want read-only access to the data, then go with a raw DataReader; it's the fasted and most lightweight data access method.

However, if you intend to alter the data and save back to the database, then I would recommend using a DataAdapter and a DataSet (even a typed DataSet) because the DataSet class takes care of tracking changes, additions and deletions to the set which makes saves much easier.  Additionally, if you have multiple tables in the dataset, you can model the referential constraints between them in the dataset.